# Build system on Linux that doesn't rely on make

Tags: linux, build, gnu-make

In GNU/Linux the use of GNU `make` and Makefiles is very common but not entirely satisfying. I am aware of tools like `autotools` and `CMake` but ultimately they still generates a Makefile, (in the case of `CMake`)at least on Linux. It is just automating the process of generating the Makefile.

I am wondering what build systems there are on Linux that do not require one to execute GNU `make` or even have GNU `make` installed and what advandages/disadvantages they have compared to GNU `make`.

Similar information related to POSIX `make` or non-GNU Linux or Unix in general are also welcome. It would also be nice to include historical perspectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your point about cmake. There is [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), it is commonly used with cmake. CMake has multiple generators, make just being the most commonly used. More about it maybe in [cmake-generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

There is even [wiki List_of_build_automation_software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) with list of `Make-incompatible` build systems, most of them work under Linux. I've seen projects with:

- Maven
- Ant
- waf
- SCons
- QT Build System
- Rake
- Ninja
- Bazel

Comment: I think the wiki link is quite helpful. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.